# Is it possible a lock wouldn't release in a while loop

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I have two threads using a common semaphore to conduct some processing. What I noticed is Thread 1 appears to hog the semaphore, and thread 2 is never able to acquire it. My running theory is maybe through compiler optimization/thread priority, somehow it just keeps giving it to thread 1.

Thread 1:

```
while(condition) {
  mySemaphore->aquire();
  //do some stuff
  mySemaphore->release();
}
```

Thread 2:

```
mySemaphore->aquire();
//block of code i never reach...
mySemaphore->release();
```

As soon as I add a delay before Thread 1s next iteration, it allows thread 2 in. Which I think confirms my theory.

Basically for this to work I might need some sort of ordering aware lock. Does my reasoning make sense?

Comment: Theres generally good reasons why locks are not fair (as they can be _much_ more efficient if they're not). In this case lock is doing _exactly_ what it was designed for - only letting a single thread acquire it at a time. If you assume the lock will do that fairly you're relying on something which isn't guaranteed. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah I'm fine with it synchronizing and doing what its supposed to in that aspect. I'm trying to give thread 2 a chance at getting the resource. I could implement a queued lock or something which would have understanding of what thread called and give it up in order I guess

Comment: Why is giving thread 2 a chance to get the resource a good thing? As you take the lock for the whole of the `do some stuff` phase, you get no extra efficiency from multithreading (as there's no effective parallelism) - just do thread 2's work on thread 1. You need to explain what the threads are doing with the lock and then we can maybe help you design this properly.

Comment: [Note that naively using a "fair" lock _will_ slow down the system - as it will probably require scheduling an unscheduled thread which takes time.

Comment: typically you only keep the lock during a short period of time during which the thread needs to access shared data. If a thread needs to access shared data 100% of the time then it can keep the lock forever

Comment: semaphores are more for signalling than mutual exclusion... Isn't it a mutex that you need?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, Semaphores are an _old_ idea: They were invented before computers had hardware support for "locking" or "atomic" operations. They were meant to be an abstraction—independent of any particular implementation—upon which various useful synchronization and communication mechanisms could be built. If you look in older textbooks or if you look at older code, you will find plenty of examples of something called "Semaphore" being used as a mutex lock, and you will find plenty more examples of semaphores being used in other ways too.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès you could use a semphore to do the same thing if you want to though.

Comment: @MikeVine the two threads are intended to do different checks on the hardware.. the design wasn't my design, I'm just trying to understand it. Its less about efficiency and less about speed/efficiency in the entire system

Comment: @JoeCaraccio. There is a name for your problem: It's called "starvation." Thread starvation describes the situation where, in theory it should be possible for some thread to acquire a lock, but in actual practice, the timing just never works out in that thread's favor. Your `while` loop, where the entire body of the loop is locked is a classic example of how to starve a thread.

Comment: Re, "the design wasn't my design, I'm just trying to understand it." Beware! There's a lot of Bad Code out there, including, in places where you would be appalled to find it. Don't ask me how I know!

Comment: @SolomonSlow right, thats exactly whats happening, that while loop continues to run and never lets thread 2 aquire the lock